# How to add info to sofort API XML using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, model-view-controller, payment

I am going to use sofort payment API in `ASP.Net MVC`, but I am having issue to add info in following XML format in C#.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<multipay>      
    <project_id>53245</project_id>
    <interface_version>pn_test_1</interface_version>
    <amount>2.20</amount>
    <currency_code>EUR</currency_code>
    <reasons>
        <reason>Testueberweisung</reason>
        <reason>-TRANSACTION-</reason>
    </reasons>
    <user_variables>
        <user_variable>test</user_variable>
    </user_variables>
    <success_url>xyz</success_url>
    <success_link_redirect>1</success_link_redirect>
    <abort_url>xyz</abort_url>
    <notification_urls>
        <notification_url>xyz</notification_url>
        <notification_url notify_on="received,loss">xyz</notification_url>
    </notification_urls>
    <su />
</multipay>
```

Comment: Describe the exact issue you're having; if you post any error messages, it will be far more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
var xmlRequest = new XElement("multipay",
new XElement("project_id", "53245"),
new XElement("interface_version", "pn_test_1"),
new XElement("amount", "2.20"),
new XElement("currency_code", "EUR"),
new XElement("reasons", new XElement("reason", "Testueberweisung"), new XElement("reason", "-TRANSACTION-"))
);
```

string xmlreq = xmlRequest.ToString();